# How to understand uniform integrability?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, uniform-integrability

From the definition to [uniform integrability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability), I could not understand why "uniform" is used as qualifier.  Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Uniformly in the sense that the same $\delta$ works for each $\epsilon$, and each function.

Comment: @user54092 What $\epsilon/\delta$ are you referring to? Certainly it makes no sense to say that there is a single $\delta$ for which $E[|X|;A] < \epsilon$ whenever $P(A) < \delta$.

Comment: @snarski The $\delta$ referred to the measure of the domain of integration.

Comment: Is it possible to relate this "uniform" qualifier to a more familiar usage in real analysis?

Comment: @user78219 This *is* the most standard usage of uniform in real analysis. Uniform continuity: for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta$ such that for all $x$ ... ; uniform convergence: for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $n$ such that for all $f$ ... ; uniform integrability: for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $k$ such that for all $X$ ... [or equivalently, there is a $\delta$ such that for all $A$ ...]

Comment: I couldn't quite see the equivalence of k/X and $delta/A$ statements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Many arguments in probability use truncation: take a random variable $X$ and define $X^k := X1_{|X| \leq k}$. This allows us to handle "most of $X$" on a compact set $K:= [-k,k]$ if $X$ is integrable, as $E|X-X^k| < \epsilon$ for sufficiently large $k$. In other words,
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow\infty} E|X1_{|X| > k}| = 0.$$
The point of *uniform* integrability is to have a single $k$ which works for a family $\{X_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ of random variables. That is, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a single, uniform $k$ for which $E|X_\alpha 1_{|X| > k}| < \epsilon$. Hence,
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \sup_{\alpha \in A} E|X1_{|X| > k}| = 0.$$

Comment: What does $A$ represent?

Comment: $A$ is just an arbitrary index set. $\sup_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$ or $\sup_{X \in \mathcal{C}} X$ (as on the wikipedia page) are the same thing. Usually the family is countable, so you have $\sup_{n \geq 1} X_n$.